# .bat file: execute command if file modified after main command was started

Tags: windows, batch, date-time

I have a .bat file executing several commands:

1. Compiling a document with `pdflatex` and externalizing the `tikzpicture` creation into .pdf files if some modifications were made since last compilation
2. Executing the following .bat file: within the current directory, on all sub-directories, on all the files in these sub-directories:

- If it is a .pdf file, execute `pdftk` to uncompress it in a .txt file
- Extract the positions of the hyperlinks from the .txt file with `extractURIs.pl`

The code for this second .bat file is:

```
for /d %%i in (%cd%\*) do ( cd "%%i" &  for %%f in (*.pdf) do pdftk %%f output Uncompressed%%~nf.txt uncompress && .\extractURIs.pl %%i %1 Uncompressed%2)
```

3. Compile a new document with `pdflatex` using the images in the .pdf files compiled in step 1. and add the links from the .txt files created in step 2.

In itself, this solution works fine but is very long to execute which could be avoided: if there is no moditication in the `tikzpicture` in step one, the existing .pdf file is not modified and step 2. could be executed only for files with a modification date more recent than the begining of the main.bat file execution.

How can I:

1. Get the time (date and time) at witch the main .bat file starts its execution and pass it as a parameter to the second .bat file
2. Modify the given code for `do (...)` to be executed only in the file `%%f` was modified/created after the execution starting time?

*I am on Windows 10 with very limited knowledge of `batch`*

Comment: @DrinkSomePimpJuiceIT Did you post this comment on the wrong question?

Comment: Maybe but I would use PowerShell for this task if possible instead.